# how can I force puppet to use port collection in freebsd?

Tags: freebsd, puppet

I've just tried basic puppet manifest which actually takes around 23 seconds to apply.

```
root@ovh:/root # cat freebsd.pp
package { '*./editors/vim':
    ensure => installed,
}
```

after adding --debug switch, it clearly seen how puppet every time reinstalls vim package with pkg_add.

q1) how force puppet to use port collection maybe with some portmaster or any other port management utility?

q2) Is this package name would be also valid for linux distros? Or I should make two `file` entries with different `provider`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does dropping the wildcard and supplying a provider help speed things up?

```
package { 'editors/vim':
    ensure => 'installed',
    provider => 'ports',
}
```

to add support for multiple operating systems you can use:

```
case $operatingsystem {
    centos, redhat: { 
        $provider = "yum",
        $vim = "vim", 
    }
    freebsd: { 
        $provider = "ports", 
        $vim = "editors/vim", 
    }
    default: { fail("Unrecognized operating system") }

}

package { $vim:
    ensure => 'installed',
    provider => $provider,
}
```